# how to Get value from chrome.storage.local through key

Tags: javascript

i think i undersatnd what's the issue is
the 'Keys' dont just carry the value

if anyone can help with the syntax?

```js
value [];
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) {
      var Keys = Object.keys(items);

      console.log(Keys);
      i= Keys.length;

console.log(items.tile); // value with tile as key = 10456 working
var str = String(Keys[6]);
console.log(str); // tile
console.log(items.str);//why this one is not working
    // console.log(test);
     while ( i-- ) {
 
          values.push(items.Keys[i]) ;
      console.log(values);
  
    }
    
    )
```

Comment: Object.entries has both keys and values - if that helps

Comment: If counting down with a loop usually the decrement goes within the loop and the condition must be a compaision. ex. `while (i >= 0 ) {   i--`...

Comment: It should be `items[str]`

Comment: See [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896)